# A strange question about the subset (of $\Bbb N$) of number $4n + 1$; wrong proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Long introduction (I'm sorry), but very short question

You take the proper subset of $\mathbb{N}$ made by all and only numbers 
of the form  $4n + 1$, when $n = 0,1,2,\ldots$ and obtain the set :
$A = \{1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,\ldots\}$

$A$ is closed with ordinary product because for any $n$,$m$ of $\mathbb{N}$: 
$(4n+1)(4m+1) = 16nm + 4n + 4m + 1 = 4(4nm+n+m)+1 = 4k + 1 $

Now, in this set $A$, the numbers $9,13,17,21$ (and others) are 
"prime" because they have no factors in $A$.

$9$  and $21$ are not really prime, of course. They are "prime" in 
the set $A$, because in $A$ there are actually no factors of those
numbers.

I will call a "prime" in $A$ A-prime (Ap), and for a prime in $\mathbb{N}$ (so, a real prime) simply prime (p).

Obviously if a number is an Ap not necessarily is a p.
But if it is a p -and belong to $A$- then it is also an Ap.

Then I will say that a number $Aq$ is a square in $A$ ($A$-square) 
if and only if there exists an $Am$ in $A$ such that $Am^2 = Aq$.

So (for example) the first $A$-square in $A$ is $25$, not $9$.

If $Aq$ is an  $A$-square then  it is also square (in $\mathbb{N}$) but the inverse is false, so the set of the A-square numbers is a proper subset of 
the all squares of $\mathbb{N}$.

**Here is the question :**
Are there numbers in $A$ not $A$-square (but eventually square), in other words numbers like $Ay$ such that you can find (in $A$) a pair $An^2$, $Am^2$
 that $An^2 = Ay\cdot Am^2$ ?

I refer to the proof kindly offered by Mister Sinclair :

I think is probably (or may be I should say "perhaps") wrong because :

It is true that
$k=3 \pmod 4$ and  $k= 3 \pmod 4$ and it is true that $n = 1 \pmod 4$.
But, although it is NOT true that $1 = 3 \pmod 4$, it IS TRUE that
$1^2=3^2 \pmod 4$ ($1 = 9 \pmod 4$).

Hence, no contradiction rises up.

The problem is (perhaps) a little bit "sneaky" and resembles 
to the following one:

It is TRUE that $(−6)^2 = 3^2\cdot2^2$, so the three number $−6,3,2$ actually 
satisfy the identity.

But it NOT true that $−6=3\cdot2$.

So, I think the problem is not resolved yet

Thank you a lot for any clarification

Comment: Hooops ... ! Last part of message is in Italian language, sorry. Anyway is not essentiale for understanding the questione (I hope) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Pardon me for dropping the $A$ prefixes, which just make the notation clunky. You are looking for integers $n,m,y \equiv 1 \mod 4$ such that $n^2 = y m^2$, but with $y \ne p^2$ for any $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Since these are integers, $y = k^2$ for some $k$. By the condition on $y$, $k \not \equiv 1 \mod 4$. But since $y$ is odd, it must be that $k \equiv 3 \mod 4$. But also, $n = km$, and therefore $n \equiv km \mod 4$. But that means $1 \equiv 3 \cdot 1 \mod 4$, which is false.

Thus no such trio $m, n, y$ can exist.

Comment: Thank you a lot Mister Sinclair, but why y must be different from any prime    p^2 such that p = 1 mod 4 ?

Comment: Sinclair, the $p$ doesn't have to be prime. I'm not sure if it's your mistake or your misleading notation. Other than that it seems fine. Change the $p$ to a non-misleading letter.

Comment: @Massimiliano $y\neq p^2$ means that $y$ must not be Asquare. The $p$ doesn't have to be prime.

Comment: I think what he is saying is: n = 1 mod 4, m = 1 mod 4, k != 1 mod 4, y = k'^2 = 1 mod 4.  You asked if it's possible for n^2 = y*m^2.  Paul Sinclair showed this was impossible.  y is odd, y i=k^2.  So k = 3 mod 4.  n^2 = y*m^2.  Take the square root of both sides.  n = k*m.  n = 1 mod 4.  k*m = 3*1 mod 4 = 3 mod 4.  Those are contradictory.

Comment: I did not state anywhere that $p$ was prime. There is no universal requirement that $p$ can only represent prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_1$ be the set of primes $\equiv 1\pmod 4$ and $P_3$ the set of primes $\equiv 3\pmod 4$. Then we can write any $n\in\mathbb N$ as
$$ n=2^r\cdot\prod_{p\in P_1}p^{s_p}\cdot\prod_{p\in P_3}p^{t_p}.$$
Note that
$$n\in A\iff r=0\text{ and }\sum s_p\text{ is even} $$
$$n\text{ is a perfect square}\iff 2|r\text{, and } 2|s_p\text{ for all $p\in P_1$}\text{, and } 2|t_p \text{ for all $p\in P_3$} $$
$$ n\text{ is an $A$-square}\iff r=0\text{, and all $s_p$ and all $t_p$ are even, and }4\mid \sum s_p$$
Thus the quotient of two $A$-squares (if it is an integer at all) has the following property (obtained by taking the difference of exponents)

- $r=0$ because $0-0=0$
- All $s_p$ and all $t_p$  are even because the difference of two evens is even
- $4\mid \sum s_p$ because the difference of two multiples of $4$ is a multiple of $4$.

Hence the quotient of two $A$-squares is an $A$-square or not even an integer.